# Connecting Yii2 with remote mongodb database using ssh

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb using this configuration in web.php:

```
'mongodb' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://user:password@10.16.22.72:27017/mobiledata_db',
        'options' => [
            "username" => "********",
            "password" => "*******"
        ]
    ],
```

and it's throwing the following error

> MongoDB Exception – yii\mongodb\Exception
>   No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster on '10.16.22.72:27017']
>   ↵
>   Caused by: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException
>   No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster on '10.16.22.72:27017']

To mention that i'm able to connect to mongo using compass and ssh.

Do i have to use ssh in connection string? If so how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

To do that i ha to set up a tunneled ssh:

ssh -fNg -L 27017:127.0.0.1:27017 user@host

And that fixed my problem.